# Asp .Net usercontrol referencing other usercontrol from markup

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, properties, markup

I’m looking for a way to pass in the markup of an user control, a reference to other usercontrol existing in the page. At this moment I’m doing this having a string property with the name of the control, and in the codebehind I use FindControl to get it, this way:

```
  <uc2:ctlMyControl ID="MyControl1" runat="server"
       ReferencedControl="TheIdOfOtherControlInThePage"  />
```

And in server side:

```
  public string mvarReferencedControl= "";
  public string ReferencedControl {
    get
    {
        return mvarReferencedControl;
    }
    set
    {
        mvarReferencedControl = value;
    }
  }
```

What I want to know is if there is a better way to do this, passing not the string with the name of the control but the control itself in a “Control” property, so I have directly the reference to the control and avoiding to do the FindControl.

Comment: What exactly to want to achieve ?>

Comment: Not when you want to set it in the markup since it must be serializable. But otherwise that's no problem. You can always return a reference to another control of your UserControl/Page in a property.

Comment: So you think that it can be achived making the usercontrol serializable, Tim?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with doing it in the code behind of your page?

```
((MyControl)MyControl1).ReferenceControl = theOtherControl;
```

Comment: I assume that the OP wants to define the control he wants to reference via markup.

Comment: Yes, i know it can be done in code behind, but i was searching for a way of doing it in the markup. Anyway thanks for the idea.